# Adding an onMouseDown attribute equivalent to each anchor's HREF attribute in a class or document

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, onmousedown

I'm having trouble getting an `onMouseDown` function that takes each link and copies the original HREF attribute of its respective anchor tag in a page and loads the URL on the down event.

Let's call this function `loadURL()`.

Right now I'm testing the function in-line for each anchor and am having trouble getting different values for each HREF attribute. I would like to make an `onLoad` function that essentially adds the `onMouseDow`n attribute and `loadURL` function to every anchor. Here's the JQuery code I have now.

**PROBLEM SOLVED, SHOWING INITIAL PROBLEM FOR REFERENCE**

Script:

```
function loadURL()
        {
            var url = $('a').attr('href');
            location.href = url;
        }
function mouseDownerURL () {
    $('a').attr('onmousedown', 'loadURL()' );
}
```

HTML

```
<body onLoad="mouseDownerURL();">
<a onmousedown="" href="foo.com">Takes you to foo.com on mouseDown</a>
<a onmousedown="" href="bar.com">Leads to foo.com NOT bar.com on mouseDown</a>
</body>
```

**SOLUTION**

```
function mouseDownerURL() {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('a').mousedown(function() {
                window.location.href = this.href;
            });
        });
    }
<body onLoad="mouseDownerURL();">
<a href="1">1</a>
<a href="2">2</a>
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of all of those functions and `onload` things and just do it normally:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').mousedown(function() {
        windows.location.href = this.href;
    });
});
```

Your problem is this line:

```
var url = $('a').attr('href');
```

`$('a')` selects *all* of the `<a>` tags, not the one that was clicked. To work around that, you have to pass the element into your function via an argument, but that's not a great idea.

Comment: for some reason this isn't triggering onMouseDown. I'm placing this code within script tags after sourcing jQuery and it's not having any affect. Firefox btw.

Comment: the 's' in windows.location.href was breaking this. Removing it solved the issue. Thanks a ton!